# Trailing whitespace in collapsed vote score

Tags: bug, design, score, whitespace

This one is a design nitpick that I think is worth posting because I've noticed it repeatedly. There's a trailing whitespace in the collapsed vote score if we select it:

[image: vote score collapsed]

But if we compare it with the the expanded vote scores there's no trailing whitespace:

[image: vote score expanded]